# Dialog with TinyMCE link-popup loses focus after tab on Mac

Tags: tinymce-4, office-js

I have a dialog with a TinyMCE editor opened from a taskpane add-in that has some weird behavior on Mac.

The trouble starts when the editor in the dialog opens a standard link popup and start tabbing afterwards. When tabbing back to the word window the behavior varies from device to device and so far I have experiences 3 different cases:

1. - Word window **not** maximized: Works
   - Word window maximized: TinyMCE popup freezes
2. - Word window **not** maximized: TinyMCE popup freezes
   - Word window maximized: Word dialog freezes
3. - Word window **not** maximized: TinyMCE popup freezes
   - Word window maximized: TinyMCE popup freezes

In all cases resizing the dialog unfreezes everything, so it seems that somehow the Word window loses more or less focus after tabbing.

A minimum working example is

1. Opening the following code in a dialog window
2. Open the link popup in TinyMCE
3. Tab to another window and back to the Word window with Word maximized

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Link</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="//cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        tinymce.init({
            selector: 'textarea',
            plugins: 'link',
            toolbar: 'link'
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <textarea></textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Let me forward this to the team

Comment: Sounds good @MichaelZlatkovsky

Comment: Hi @MichaelZlatkovsky, do you have an update on this matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We acknowledge the issue, it is a product bug and will be fixed with 15.28 release in November.